# How to make recyclerView go up when new message arrive in Android?

Tags: android

I am creating a chatting app and everything is fine but when message fill screen and new message arrive I have to scroll the recyclerView up manually. What I want is that I want the new message to push recycler View up.

[image]

For the reverse layout I am using `linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`

Comment: Have you tried scrolling the 'RecyclerView' to the latest item once the new message is added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new item from your `model-class` and use this `notifyItemInserted` function to refresh the new item without change the pervious items. This can be helpful if you are making chat-box or comment section.

```
   modelclass.add(index, values);
   adapter.notifyItemInserted(index);
   recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(index);
```

By this function you can check if that item is already in the list or not by its id.

```
  boolean contains(List<modelclass> list, String id) {
        for (modelclass item : list) {
            if (item.getId().equals(id)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Call list function after some interval by **Handler** :

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000;
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                updatelist();
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
```